# Python: trouble updating metadata in Salesforce report Rest API request to get report over 2000 rows

Tags: python, api, python-requests, salesforce, metadata

I want to pull a report which is over 2000 rows from Salesforce via API using python. How do I update the post request to send the updated metadata with the new filters in order to get the next 2000 rows of data? Here is the code I have, but the response of the post-request has the same exact filters as before. What am I doing wrong here?

Excerpt of Code:

```
headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token
    }
parameters={}
descripion = requests.request('get', instance_url+'/services/data/v51.0/analytics/reports/00O4Q000009VEPCUA4/describe',
                              headers=headers, params=parameters, timeout=30).json()

orig_metadata = descripion['reportMetadata']
id_column='CUST_NAME'
last_load_num='162451'
sf_id_column = descripion['reportExtendedMetadata']['detailColumnInfo'][id_column]['label']
print(sf_id_column)

metadata = {
    'reportBooleanFilter': '({}) AND {}'.format(orig_metadata['reportBooleanFilter'],
                                                len(orig_metadata['reportFilters']) + 1),
    
    'reportFilters': orig_metadata['reportFilters']+[{'column':id_column,
                                                      'filterType': 'fieldValue',
                                                      'isRunPageEditable': True,
                                                      'operator': 'greaterThan',
                                                      'value': last_load_num}],
    'standardDateFilter':[{'column': 'CUST_CREATED_DATE','durationValue': 'CUSTOM',
                           'endDate': '2021-07-14','startDate': '2021-07-01'}],
    'detailColumns': orig_metadata['detailColumns'][:],
    'sortBy': [{'sortColumn': id_column, 'sortOrder': 'Asc'}],
}

r=requests.request('post', instance_url+'/services/data/v51.0/analytics/reports/00O4Q000009VEPCUA4',
                   headers=headers, params={'metadata':metadata}, timeout=30).json()
```

**Here is what's in the original metadata**:

```
{'aggregates': ['s!rtms__Load__c.rtms__Carrier_Quote_Total__c', 'RowCount'],
 'chart': None,
 'crossFilters': [],
 'currency': None,
 'dashboardSetting': None,
 'description': None,
 'detailColumns': ['CUST_NAME',
  'CUST_CREATED_DATE',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Expected_Ship_Date2__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Load_Status__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Total_Weight__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Equipment_Type__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Origin__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Destination__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Zip3_Lane__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Zip5_Lane__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Carrier_Quote_Total__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Customer_Quote_Total__c'],
 'developerName': 'Adel_Past_Shipment_Test_Pricing_Tool',
 'division': None,
 'folderId': '00l1U000000eXWwQAM',
 'groupingsAcross': [],
 'groupingsDown': [],
 'hasDetailRows': True,
 'hasRecordCount': True,
 'historicalSnapshotDates': [],
 'id': '00O4Q000009VEPCUA4',
 'name': 'Adel Past Shipment Test Pricing Tool',
 'presentationOptions': {'hasStackedSummaries': True},
 'reportBooleanFilter': None,
 'reportFilters': [{'column': 'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Customer__c',
   'filterType': 'fieldValue',
   'isRunPageEditable': True,
   'operator': 'contains',
   'value': 'adel'},
  {'column': 'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Load_Status__c',
   'filterType': 'fieldValue',
   'isRunPageEditable': True,
   'operator': 'notContain',
   'value': 'cancelled'}],
 'reportFormat': 'TABULAR',
 'reportType': {'label': 'Loads', 'type': 'CustomEntity$rtms__Load__c'},
 'scope': 'organization',
 'showGrandTotal': True,
 'showSubtotals': True,
 'sortBy': [{'sortColumn': 'CUST_CREATED_DATE', 'sortOrder': 'Desc'}],
 'standardDateFilter': {'column': 'CUST_CREATED_DATE',
  'durationValue': 'CUSTOM',
  'endDate': None,
  'startDate': None},
 'standardFilters': None,
 'supportsRoleHierarchy': False,
 'userOrHierarchyFilterId': None}
```

**And here is what's in r['reportMetadata']:**

```
{'aggregates': ['s!rtms__Load__c.rtms__Carrier_Quote_Total__c', 'RowCount'],
 'chart': None,
 'crossFilters': [],
 'currency': None,
 'dashboardSetting': None,
 'description': None,
 'detailColumns': ['CUST_NAME',
  'CUST_CREATED_DATE',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Expected_Ship_Date2__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Load_Status__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Total_Weight__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Equipment_Type__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Origin__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Destination__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Zip3_Lane__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Zip5_Lane__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Carrier_Quote_Total__c',
  'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Customer_Quote_Total__c'],
 'developerName': 'Adel_Past_Shipment_Test_Pricing_Tool',
 'division': None,
 'folderId': '00l1U000000eXWwQAM',
 'groupingsAcross': [],
 'groupingsDown': [],
 'hasDetailRows': True,
 'hasRecordCount': True,
 'historicalSnapshotDates': [],
 'id': '00O4Q000009VEPCUA4',
 'name': 'Adel Past Shipment Test Pricing Tool',
 'presentationOptions': {'hasStackedSummaries': True},
 'reportBooleanFilter': None,
 'reportFilters': [{'column': 'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Customer__c',
   'filterType': 'fieldValue',
   'isRunPageEditable': True,
   'operator': 'contains',
   'value': 'adel'},
  {'column': 'rtms__Load__c.rtms__Load_Status__c',
   'filterType': 'fieldValue',
   'isRunPageEditable': True,
   'operator': 'notContain',
   'value': 'cancelled'}],
 'reportFormat': 'TABULAR',
 'reportType': {'label': 'Loads', 'type': 'CustomEntity$rtms__Load__c'},
 'scope': 'organization',
 'showGrandTotal': True,
 'showSubtotals': True,
 'sortBy': [{'sortColumn': 'CUST_CREATED_DATE', 'sortOrder': 'Desc'}],
 'standardDateFilter': {'column': 'CUST_CREATED_DATE',
  'durationValue': 'CUSTOM',
  'endDate': None,
  'startDate': None},
 'standardFilters': None,
 'supportsRoleHierarchy': False,
 'userOrHierarchyFilterId': None}
```

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irfPx.png)

Comment: Looks like you can use either `allData` or `rowLimit` to change the number of results returned. Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_report_query.htm).

Comment: Yes, I have tried using allData but it would still limit the response to 2000 rows.